# SSH Tunneling, have some problems

Tags: ssh, tunneling, forwarding, port

I have a computer and host A, B. Host A has internet connection and host B placed in host's A local network. Host B has Web Interface at port 8080. I need to forward port on host A. And then i want to get web interface of host b on host A from internet.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? Confirm that you want to access Host A from the internet (public IP address) and have it tunnelled to the actual web interface on Host B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When accessing Host A by its public IP address using ssh:

```
ssh -L -f -N -T <local port>:<host B IP address>:8080 <host A public IP address>:<forwarded port>
```

This will set up the tunnel for you and run in the background. You can then open a browser and type either `localhost:<local port>` or `127.0.0.1:<local port>` and it should tunnel through Host A to Host B.

The `-L` sets up forwarding from your local host that you're using to access Host A's public IP.

The `-f` tells ssh to run in the background since you don't need an interactive session.

The `-N` tells ssh that you don't have a remote command to execute, just the tunnel.

The `-T` disables allocation of a pseudo terminal.

Note that this assumes you have your firewall set up correctly to forward the `<forwarded port>`, which isn't really an ssh issue.